# remote console connection mac

Tags: mac, console, ssh, remote

My strato server is blocked due to a DoS-attack. In order to solve this problem I need to connect to my server via a remote console. The strato FAQ is not sufficient for me. Can anyone explain me how and with which program I can make this type of connection?

Thanks.

Comment: If your server is under attack by a DENIAL OF SERVICE attack, you will not be able to access it, or it will be really slow.  However, if you are using a mac, open up the terminal, type ssh username@server , enter, type in your password, and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Terminal and type:

```
ssh user@hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

If just your web server is under DoS attack, then you should be able to ssh into the box as suggested by chris.

However, if it's a general DoS, that will block any incoming network connections. Your only hope is if the hosting provider, strato, has a back channel to a console session. You'll need to check with the hosting provider -- each one will handle this differently.